# Make errors - ec_asn1.o - ec_asn1.c:201: error: expected expression before 'X9_62_PENTANOMIAL'

Tags: linux, redhat, openssl

I am trying to install a separate version of Openssl 1.0.1k on Red Hat. I tried on Centos first with no real issues.

Before getting to this error I did the following:

```
yum install -y libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel    #not sure if this actually helped with my errors. 
./config --prefix=/data/home/jboss/openssl_1.0.1/usr         \
         --openssldir=/data/home/jboss/openssl_1.0.1/etc/ssl
# missing include files. 
vi ~/.bash_profile
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/bcc/include/
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/bcc/include/
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
LANG=en_US           # make was giving accented a special characters. This fixed. I would set it back once I fixed to en_US.UTF-8. 
vi /usr/lib/bcc/include/asm/limits.h
define INT_MAX              2147483647
```

After all of that, I am getting the following:

```
.... more on top
make[2]: Entering directory `/data01/home/s617741/openssl-1.0.1k/crypto/bn'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/data01/home/s617741/openssl-1.0.1k/crypto/bn'
making all in crypto/ec...
make[2]: Entering directory `/data01/home/s617741/openssl-1.0.1k/crypto/ec'
gcc -I.. -I../.. -I../modes -I../asn1 -I../evp -I../../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM   -c -o ec_asn1.o ec_asn1.c
ec_asn1.c:201: warning: implicit declaration of function 'offsetof'
ec_asn1.c:201: error: expected expression before 'X9_62_PENTANOMIAL'
ec_asn1.c:201: error: initializer element is not constant
ec_asn1.c:201: error: (near initialization for 'X9_62_PENTANOMIAL_seq_tt[0].offset')
ec_asn1.c:202: error: expected expression before 'X9_62_PENTANOMIAL'
ec_asn1.c:202: error: initializer element is not constant
ec_asn1.c:202: error: (near initialization for 'X9_62_PENTANOMIAL_seq_tt[1].offset')
ec_asn1.c:203: error: expected expression before 'X9_62_PENTANOMIAL'
ec_asn1.c:203: error: initializer element is not constant
ec_asn1.c:203: error: (near initialization for 'X9_62_PENTANOMIAL_seq_tt[2].offset')
... continues with similar errors.
```

Any insight would help.

Answer (score 2):

`offsetof` is defined in is defined in `<stddef.h>`, and used by `ec_asn1.c` and `rand_egd.c`.

However, `ec_asn1.c` and `rand_egd.c` do not include `<stddef.h>`:

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.1
$ find . -iname ec_asn1.c
./crypto/ec/ec_asn1.c
$ cat crypto/ec/ec_asn1.c | grep stddef
```

You should open `ec_asn1.c` and `rand_egd.c`, and add `#include <stddef.h>`.

### -----

A bug was filed against OpenSSL for this issue: [Bug 3684: Missing <stddef.h> for source files using offsetof](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3684). You can check the status in their [RT Tracker](http://rt.openssl.org/). Login with username=guest, password=guest.

### -----

Here's the definition from the machine I am working on in case you need it:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ == 3 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 5 || __GNUC__ > 3)
#ifndef __offsetof      /* Deprecated: for source compatibility only */
#define __offsetof(type, field) __builtin_offsetof(type, field)
#endif
#define offsetof(type, field) __builtin_offsetof(type, field)
#else /* ! (gcc >= 3.5) */
#ifndef __offsetof      /* Deprecated: for source compatibility only */
#define __offsetof(type, field) ((size_t)(&((type *)0)->field))
#endif
#define offsetof(type, field) ((size_t)(&((type *)0)->field))
#endif /* (gcc >= 3.5) */
```